# How to pass Java InputStream to JRuby io that supports pos/seek

Tags: ruby, jruby, inputstream

I need to call a (j)ruby script from java runtime, and I want to pass an input stream as a parameter.

On the ruby side, I'm using to_io to convert input stream

```
io = my_stream.to_io
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (Errno::ESPIPE) Illegal seek
at org.jruby.RubyIO.pos(org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1602) ~[jruby-core-1.7.4.jar:na]
```

The question is, are there better options to convert input stream to io that support pos and seek?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stream is coming in as a pipe and that is not seekable.  Since seek and pos won't work properly on a pipe you would have to read from the pipe.

io_stream.read(number_of_bytes)